# How to split array from specific index swift 3?

Tags: arrays, swift, split, slice

For example I have an array of let `arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`. I want to get the value from index 5th to the last and the rest I want to throw it away. Any idea of this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
arr[5..<arr.count]
```

It will print `[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`. Adjust your index accordingly if you need it to start from a different index. Also make sure you check `arr` has more than 5 elements.

if you need to get this as an array try this `Array(arr[5..<arr.count])`

Comment: Please search for duplicates before rushing to post an answer.

Comment: But the answers given in other question doesn't have this one. This is the easy route. They made it too complicated there. By the way how do you search for duplicates?

Comment: Then add your answer to the other question if you feel it will help others. Then that other question becomes a better duplicate any time some asks this type of question.

Comment: Ok thanks. I didnt know other question existed before I put this answer here.

Comment: That's fine. Just something to consider next time.

Comment: I works for small array like this, but my array is actually large meaning that it's not fix like this

Comment: @rmaddy could you please give me the duplicates you mention?

Comment: @EKChhuon Why not? This will work for any size of array. What is the issue you faced with large array? If this didn't work, any other answer will not work too. `largeArray = largeArray[5000..<arr.count]`. Try this on your large array.

Comment: @EKChhuon Look at the top of your question (refresh the page if you need to).

Comment: @EKChhuon, Were you able to get this working? Did you try my update `Array(arr[5..<arr.count])`?

Comment: Is there a way to get the array inclusive of the left index?

Comment: Easiest option is, instead of 5, use (5 - 1) which is 4 in this case.